# Agglomerative clustering using DTW distance matrix

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis

I am trying to cluster a dataset of time series. For this I have computed pairwise DTW distance. These data is collected in a distance matrix which I would like to use as input for AgglomerativeClustering() sklearn method.

It seems I need to use a condensed distance matrix for it. But if I do that, the clustering method interprets each distance as a new sample so I get too many labels. How should I properly do this?

This is a sample code I have tried:

```
import numpy as np

# Test symmetric matrix
N = 4
b = np.random.randint(0,5,size=(N,N))
b_symm = (b + b.T)/2
np.fill_diagonal(b_symm,np.zeros(N))

# Condensed matrix
condensed = squareform(b_symm)
model = AgglomerativeClustering(n_clusters=2, linkage=linkage)
y = model.fit_predict(condensed.reshape(-1,1))
```

Comment: Is there a reason you *have* to use a condensed distance matrix?  You could just as easily `squareform` it to a normal distance matrix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see the documentation:

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.AgglomerativeClustering.html

> affinity : string or callable, default: “euclidean”
>
> Metric used to compute the linkage. Can be “euclidean”, “l1”, “l2”, “manhattan”, “cosine”, or ‘**precomputed**’. If linkage is “ward”, only “euclidean” is accepted.